# Problem making Python install praw - syntax error?

Tags: python, windows, installation, praw

Every guide I've found on the web says that all I have to do to install PRAW is type in:

```
>> pip install praw
```

However, I've been trying to do that for an hour and it just keeps saying 'invalid syntax'. I tried on windows command prompt, and that doesn't work.  I installed PIP when I installed python, but I'm not seeing a python install on my C:\ drive and no matter how many times I reinstall I can't make this work. It's driving me nuts. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm on Windows 10 with the latest version of Python

Comment: You're running this command in the Python console. Don't do that, run it in powershell or cmd.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't install for PATH. This was easy to miss as it's tiny and on the first installer page. It also didn't totally solve the problem, but did allow me to install PRAW.